# Why not print the date?

Tags: javascript, node.js, node.js-connect, node.js-client

This is my code, there are 2 files:

file b.js

```
module.exports.data = function() {
    return new Date();
}
```

file a.js

```
var a = require("./b")
var http = require('http')
http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-type':'text/plain'})
    res.write('the date is: '+a.data)
    res.end();
}).listen(8000)
```

Why not print the date?

Comment: You need to use `a.data()` not `a.data`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to call the data function

```
var a = require("./b")
var http = require('http')
http.createServer(function(req, res){

    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-type':'text/plain'})

    res.write('the date is: '+a.data())

    res.end();



}).listen(8000)
```

Answer (score 2):

a.data is a function, may call it:

```
res.write('the date is: '+a.data());
```

Or you use a *getter* :

```
module.exports = {
  get date(){
     return new Date();
  }
 };
```

Then you can do:

```
res.write("date is "+a.date);
```

Answer (score 0):

A simpler way of doing this will be:
1) In b.js:

```
module.exports={
 data:new Date()
}
```